# Resharper: Possible Multiple Enumeration of IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, resharper, ienumerable, optimization

I'm using the new Resharper version 6. In several places in my code it has underlined some text and warned me that there may be a *Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable*.

I understand what this means, and have taken the advice where appropriate, but in some cases I'm not sure it's actually a big deal.

Like in the following code:

```
var properties = Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(this).GetModifiedProperties();
if (properties.Contains("Property1") || properties.Contains("Property2") || properties.Contains("Property3")) {
    ...
}
```

It's underlining each mention of `properties` on the second line, warning that I am enumerating over this IEnumerable multiple times.

If I add `.ToList()` to the end of line 1 (turning `properties` from a `IEnumerable<string>` to a `List<string>`), the warnings go away.

But surely, if I convert it to a List, then it will enumerate over the entire IEnumerable to build the List in the first place, and then enumerate over the List as required to find the properties (i.e. 1 full enumeration, and 3 partial enumerations). Whereas in my original code, it is only doing the 3 partial enumerations.

Am I wrong? What is the best method here?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your `properties` really is here - but if it's essentially representing an unmaterialized database query, then your `if` statement will perform three queries.

I *suspect* it would be better to do:

```
string[] propertiesToFind = { "Property1", "Property2", "Property3" };
if (properties.Any(x => propertiesToFind.Contains(x))
{
     ...
}
```

That will *logically* only iterate over the sequence once - and if there's a database query involved, it may well be able to just use a SQL "IN" clause to do it all in the database in a single query.

Comment: Are you sure that it wont iterate through properties and invoke Contains() three times with this? That seems programatically logical, however I do understand that it would be more optimal if it could optimize it to just use one iteration. EDIT: gah, sorry, I read it in reverse...

Comment: @jishi: the point is that Contains is now done on `propertiesToFind` not `properties`

Comment: @jishi: There's only one call to `Contains` in the lambda expression, so it's only going to call `Contains` once per element... but that's calling `Contains` *on* the array. If evaluating the sequence is time-consuming (e.g. it's looking over a much larger sequence and filtering) then this will be more efficient.

Comment: The SQL IN clause could only possibly happen if properties is an IQueryable.

Answer (score 8):

If you invoke `Contains()` on a IEnumerable, it will invoke the extension method which will just iterate through the items in order to find it. `IList` has real implementation for `Contains()` that probably are more efficient than a regular iteration through the values (it might have a search tree with hashes?), hence it doesn't warn with `IList`.

Since the extension method will only be aware that it's an `IEnumerable`, it probably can not utilize any built-in methods for `Contains()` even though it would be possible in theory to identify known types and cast them accordingly in order to utilize them.