# Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, resharper, enumeration

[image]

why is that ? how can I fix it ?

Comment: All but the final screenshot and text just distract from the real question.

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/7244178/219583 . Any() will count as one enumeration and Aggregate() as the 2nd.

Comment: Don't post code as screenshots -- paste the source into the question.

Comment: This message has been brought up on StackOverflow before - the following two questions may clarify what's going on for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240844/handling-warning-for-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593825/resharper-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is nothing to fix here. `Any()` will iterate the enumeration but stop after the first element (after which it returns true).

Multiple enumerations are mainly a problem in two cases:

- Performance: Generally you want to avoid multiple iterations if you
  can, because it is slower. This does not apply here since `Any()` will
  just confirm there is at least one element and is a required check for you. Also you are not accessing any remote/external resources, just an in-memory sequence.
- Enumerations that cannot be iterated over more than once: E.g.
  receiving items from a network etc. - also does not apply here.

As a non Linq version that only needs to iterate once you *could* do the following:

```
bool foundAny= false;
bool isEqual = true;

if(f == null)
  throw new ArgumentException();

foreach(var check in f)
{
   foundAny = true;
   isEqual = isEqual && check(p,p2);
}

if(!foundAny)
  throw new ArgumentException();

return isEqual;
```

But, as noted, in your case it does not make a difference, and I would go with the version that is more readable to you.

Comment: If this was a database query it would execute twice, usually fully.

Comment: @usr: Agreed, I added that to the first case - it does make a difference in this case whether it's a remote/external resource or an in-memory sequence

Answer (score 6):

The `Any` method can cause the enumeration of the `IEnumerable<T>`, if it doesn't have another way to determine the result. In some cases it can be a problem, for instance if the `IEnumerable<T>` instance is actually an `IQueryable<T>` that will cause a database query or web service call to be executed. Now, if it's just an in-memory collection, it's not really an issue, because enumerating the collection won't have noticeable side effects. And anyway, `Any` will use the `Count` property if the sequence implements `ICollection<T>`, so it won't cause an enumeration.