# How to create an IEnumerable to get all X lazily in a single statement

Tags: c#, lambda, iterator, lazy-evaluation

C# doesn't allow lambda functions to represent iterator blocks (e.g., no "yield return" allowed inside a lambda function).  If I wanted to create a lazy enumerable that yielded all the drives at the time of enumeration for example, I'd like to do something like

```
IEnumerable<DriveInfo> drives = {foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives()) 
                                     yield return drive;};
```

It took a while, but I figured out this as a way to get that functionality:

```
var drives = Enumerable.Range(0, 1).SelectMany(_ => DriveInfo.GetDrives());
```

Is there a more idiomatic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write your own method, something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetLazily<T>(Func<IEnumerable<T>> getSource)
{
  foreach (var t in getSource())
    yield return t;
}
```

or:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetLazily<T>(Func<IEnumerable<T>> getSource)
{
  return (new int[1]).SelectMany(_ => getSource());
}
```

It ought to allow usage like this:

```
var drives = GetLazily(DriveInfo.GetDrives);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var drives = new Func<IEnumerable<DriveInfo>>(DriveInfo.GetDrives);

 foreach(var drive in drives())
     Console.WriteLine(drive);
```

This solution has an important feature; It recognizes that multiple enumeration can be potentially bad. For instance, the underlying enumerator might make snap-shot of the list and then only ever enumerate over than list. There have been other discussions on multiple-enumerators See Answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549498/possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240844/handling-warning-for-possible-multiple-enumeration-of-ienumerable)

Comment: Instead of `drives.Invoke()`, just say `drives()`.

Comment: Oh didn't know you could do that. I've been calling invoke all this time. :D

Comment: Can you qualify why multiple enumeration is bad?  I don't think it would be an issue here since the behavior would be the *intended* behavior.

Comment: Maybe your `drives` variable should be called `getDrives`? It does not have the type `IEnumerable<>` though, so it can't be passed to a method that wants an `IEnumerable<>`.